# How to convert 3d image to 2d image

Tags: image-processing

How can I convert 3D image to 2D image in order to view it without using a 3D glasses?

[image]

Update:
- I have no solution at the moment, but, you know, you can imagine that if you have a 3d image you will wear the glass to your camera and take another image (So, I think that it a physical method to convert from 3d to 2d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3d image is actually a pair of images: 1 for left eye, and 1 for right. There are many ways to transfer those from computer to your eyes including magenta/cyan (your case), polarization ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarized_3D_glasses ), animation ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Home_plate_anim.gif ) etc. The point is that 3d is two different images. There is no real way to merge them to one. If you have source images (e.g. separate images for right and lelft) you can just take one of them and that will be your 2d image.

Answer (score 2):

First pass it through `Red and Blue filters` and get the two separate images(these images will differ in their positions slightly).

Then you need to transform one image through some pixel(which you should determine - you can detect the edges in both the images and find the difference in pixels between their first edge)

This method will help you to get a 2D image.

Comment: How to do this: `get the two separate images`?

Comment: To get red channel image set the green and blue channels value of all the pixels in the image to zero. And then for the second image make the red channel values of all pixels to zero because we have to maintain the green channel in one of the two images.

Comment: Did you get what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

By using relatively straightforward image processing, you can run that source image through a red or blue filter (just like the glasses), to attempt to recover something like the original left or right eye image. You will still end up with two slightly different images, and you may have trouble recovering the original image colours.

Answer (score 0):

Split the image into Red and Green channels. Then use any stereo vision technique to match the red channel and green channel images.